# Gmsh structured mesh (Hexahedron mesh) gets imported in unstructured way (tetrahedron) into Itasca PFC software using Fipy

Tags: python-3.x, fipy, gmsh

I'm trying to import a 3D cylindrical CFD mesh into Itasca PFC7-3D software from Gmsh using Fipy. The mesh created in Gmsh environment is fully structured(hexahedron cells). However when I tried to import the mesh into Itasca I realized it is imported in unstructured way (tetrahedron). As I don't know much about Fipy, my first guess is that maybe node-ordering convention differs in Itasca and Fipy. (Fipy version 3.4.3, python version 3.6, PFC3D version 7, Gmsh version 4.11.1). Any helps is wholeheartedly appreciated. This is what I built in Gmsh [Gmsh mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGiL7.jpg). As you see mesh structure is fully Hexa. Itasca PFC is supplied with a distribution of Python 3.6 called ipython that is specifically configured for use with Itasca software. So I tried to use Fipy in order to import my Gmsh mesh into Itasca PFC. But mesh imports distorted and fully tetra. This is the output element plot in Itasca PFC [Itasca PFC mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh9vg.png)

I guessed mayby removing non-hexa elements in .msh file will do the trick(because Gmsh implements meshing first in 1D then in 2D and finally in 3D to create a 3D mesh and msh file contains all those information) but it never did. Also I tried to comprehend the node-ordering convention in both ways and applied changes in my python code but I failed.
Here's the python code piece by which I tried to import Gmsh mesh into Itasca PFC using Fipy 3.4.3 :

```
import fipy as fp
import numpy as np
from itasca import cfdarray as ca

class DarcyFlowSolution(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mesh = fp.meshes.gmshMesh.Gmsh3D(r"C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Itasca\pfc3d700\My Projects\c6") #.msh file directory
        ca.create_mesh(self.mesh.vertexCoords.T, 
           self.mesh._cellVertexIDs.T[:,(0,2,3,1,4,6,7,5)].astype(np.int64))
#itasca.cfdarray.create_mesh(nodes: array float{nnodes, 3}, elements: array int{nelem, 8}) → None.
#Create a cfd mesh. The indices in the array elem should index the node locations in the array node. Counting begins at 0.
```

Plus this is the node-ordering convention in PFC which is provided in Itasca documentation:
[node-ordering convention in PFC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfBNB.png)

Comment: "when I tried to import the mesh into Itasca I realized it is imported in unstructured way (tetrahedron)" - How did you import the mesh in Itasca? Is that the code at the end or something else? Does Itasca import Gmsh meshes natively?

Comment: "mesh plots in Gmsh and PFC + PFC node-ordering convention accordingly" - I see one plot, which I don't understand what it's showing me. Can you please explain what it is and what you expected to see?

Comment: Hello and Thank you for your contribution sir. The question edited for clarification. I hope the problem is clear now. @jeguyer

Comment: No sir. Itasca does not natively import Gmsh mesh but understands it through Fipy. In other words I imported mesh in Itasca using Fipy Gmsh mesh capability. You can see details in python code at the end of the post. @jeguyer

Comment: Thank you sir. I cant put in words how much I appreciate your generosity . Be safe. @jeguyer

Comment: To whomever keeps corn-fielding my comments, would you care to tell me why it's unacceptable to point to SO's own documentation on how to accept answers? To @HadiMorovvatju, I was happy to help.

Comment: @HadiMorovvatju: please do click below to accept the answer if you're indeed happy with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that you are getting tets. Instead, I think there are two issues:

- the nodes you pass to `create_mesh()` describe two quadrilaterals for each cell, parallel to the yz plane, whereas Itasca and Gmsh both want the two faces of a hexahedron to be parallel to the xy plane.
- `_cellVertexIDs` does not guarantee any particular ordering and I find that different cells can be mirrored and twisted with respect to each other (FiPy doesn't use `_cellVertexIDs` for anything other than testing some known meshes, so we don't care that the ordering isn't consistent). There is a separate `_orderedCellVertexIDs` property that preserves the ordering of Gmsh elements.

With the caveat that I do not have Itasca and have never used it, I think you should try

```py
ca.create_mesh(self.mesh.vertexCoords.T, 
           self.mesh._orderedCellVertexIDs.T.astype(np.int64))
```

Note, this still might not work for you because the [node-ordering convention in PFC image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfBNB.png) that you shared looks like a left-hand coordinate system to me which is... odd... Gmsh and FiPy both operate in a right-hand coordinate system.

I diagnosed with a simple two element mesh generated with

```py
mesh = fp.GmshGrid3D(dx=5, dy=4, dz=3, nx=2, ny=1, nz=1)
```

If the above doesn't work, please provide your `.msh` file and I'll try to do more diagnostics.